# Declaration in C Language

Tags: c, declaration

I tried to declaration this to C programming, but it turns out an *error*. Is there a mistake from this?

#### Error

```
poker_comp.c: In function ‘newdeck’:
poker_comp.c:40:15: warning: assignment to ‘Card *’ {aka ‘struct card *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘Card *’ {aka ‘struct card *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   40 |     deck->top = newcard(p,s);
      |               ^
poker_comp.c:41:12: warning: assignment to ‘Card ’ {aka ‘struct card *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘Card *’ {aka ‘struct card **’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   41 |     cursor = deck->top;
      |            ^
```

#### Code

```
typedef enum boolean {false, true} flipped;`
typedef struct card{
    int pips;
    char suit;
    bool flipped;
    int *nextCard;
}Card;

typedef struct deck{
    struct card[52];
    Card **cards;
}Deck;

typedef struct player{
    char name;
    int *c1, *c2;
    int acc;
}Player;
```

Comment: What error? Please update the question with exact error messages. Also, please do not post images of text -  [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as text into the question.

Comment: As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Is the stray [backtick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick#Noun) near "`typedef enum boolean {false, true} flipped;`" (the first line of code) actually in the code? Or is it a formatting error here?

Comment: The posted code and the posted errors do not seem to correspond at all.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
typedef enum boolean {false, true} flipped;`
```

is ending with a backquote, and that is wrong.

> ```
>  struct card[52];
> ```

is wrong (and is equivalent to <strike>`Card[52];`</strike>, which is also wrong); maybe you want `Card card_deck[52];` and later use `card_deck` instead of  `card`...

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (actually [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) on [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) 20) on your code `aprilia.c` as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c aprilia.c` you get error messages:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -c /tmp/aprilia.c -o /tmp/aprilia.o
aprilia.c:1:44: error: stray ‘`’ in program
    1 | typedef enum boolean {false, true} flipped;`
      |                                            ^
aprilia.c:9:16: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
    9 |     struct card[52];
      |                ^
```

#### See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. Read a good C programming book, such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/).

Refer also to some recent draft C standard, such as [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or something newer.

Consider taking inspiration from *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) coded in C, such as [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Consider also using some static analysis tool, e.g., [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (or, perhaps in mid-2021, [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)).

For [tagged union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in C, consider having some `union` field inside some `struct`.